# Where to add "No results behaviour" to a view?

Tags: views, 8

I'm using an exposed filter. When there is no result, where do I add "No results behavior" for the view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the view settings page, click on the *Add* button shown to the right of *No results behavior*. (The following screenshots are taken from the *Taxonomy term* view, but what described is valid for every view.)

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

In the dialog box that appears next, select *Text area* and click on the *Apply (all displays)* button at the bottom.

> [image: screenshot]

The button name changes to *Apply (this display)* when *This page (override)* is selected for *For* on the top.

> [image: screenshot]

In the *Content* text area that appears in the next dialog box, you can enter the text to show when no results are returned from the view.

> [image: screenshot]

If you need it, you can also use some global tokens, listed under *Available global token replacements*.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

..............Have you tried here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the view settings, it's in the middle column, between *Footer* and *pager*.

The screenshot I am showing is for the front page view that comes with Drupal 8.

> [image: screenshot]